# Disabling the free shipping method when the cart has product/s which assigned a certain shipping class

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Can you please tell me how can I adapt this snippet (it disables the free shipping method for a certain product) to make it possible to disable the free shipping method when the cart has product/s which assigned a certain shipping class? (WooCommerce 4.2+)

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
function my_free_shipping( $is_available ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // set the product ids that are ineligible
    $ineligible = array( '4743' );

    // get cart contents
    $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    
    // loop through the items looking for one in the ineligible array
    foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {
        if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $ineligible ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // nothing found return the default value
    return $is_available;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'my_free_shipping', 20 );
```

Comment: WooCommerce is a 3rd party plugin, 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic on this site. For help with WooCommerce you should contact Woo support or ask in WooCommerce communities and groups. If you were directed here for WooCommerce help let us know as that is a violation of Stack Exchange TOC's

Comment: @TomJNowell as fas I know Woo is a plugin of WP. There are tons of woo related questions here in this forum and other plugins as well such as ACF etc. So, What is your problem with my question??

Comment: WooCommerce is owned by Automattic, a 3rd party company, it isn't 1st party. The only 1st party plugins are core feature plugins such as Hello Dolly, plugins for functionality to be merged into WP itself, like the sitemaps coming in 5.5. As an ex-Automattic employee, I understand that people can confuse wp.com the paid service, and wordpress.org the open source project. I'd also note this isn't a discussion forum. Your question on its own is fine, it just doesn't fit into the scope of this site. You should ask in a WooCommerce forum or group

Comment: Take a look at https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-vs-wordpress-com/. As for other questions on this site about WooCommerce, that doesn't mean they're on topic. Moderation on this site is done by volunteers and we can't catch all questions. Also sometimes questions are related to but not about WooCommerce, and users can create tags so deleting the woocommerce tag just means it gets recreated. The description of the tag does say the subject is offtopic though, and directs users to https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce

Comment: @TomJNowell I understood your point but can you please search questions about ACF in here you can see the 2,545 results. Or just try woocommerce, the result is 3,769 questions. So, I really don't understand why you locked my question? You can notify me, I could understand that but there are thousands of questions here regarding 3rd party plugins. On the other hand, somebody already tried to help me, which means users don't get this question as you did.

Comment: Arguing in the comments will not get your question reopened, there is a process for this. Open a question on the meta stack: https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/. And as I said, just because there's another question that wasn't closed doesn't mean your question can be reopened, it just means someone needs to close the other question. Closed questions also appear in search, while looking at ACF, pay attention to the `[closed]` at the end of the question title. As I said, a question can be tagged Woo without being about Woo, and just because you got an answer doesn't mean it's on topic

Comment: @TomJNowell I am nor arguing, I don't know you, I just show you a very clear argument that you are wrong, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
function hide_shipping_methods( $available_shipping_methods, $package ) {
    $shipping_classes = array( 'some-shipping-class-1', 'some-shipping-class-2' );
    $excluded_methods = array( 'free_shipping' );
    $shipping_class_exists = false;
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $key => $value )
        if ( in_array( $value['data']->get_shipping_class(), $shipping_classes ) ) {
            $shipping_class_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    if ( $shipping_class_exists ) {
        $methods_to_exclude = array();
        foreach( $available_shipping_methods as $method => $method_obj )
            if ( in_array( $method_obj->method_id, $excluded_methods ) )
                $methods_to_exclude[] = $method;
        if ( $methods_to_exclude )
            foreach ( $methods_to_exclude as $method )
                unset( $available_shipping_methods[$method] );
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
```

Here `$shipping_classes` is array of the shipping classes slugs and `$excluded_methods` is array of excluded shipping methods if at least one of the products in the cart belongs to one of these shipping classes.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan, but It doesn't work, free_shipping still valid.

Comment: @UgurTerzi Try updated version please.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan, still no luck. free_shipping is still valid

Comment: @UgurTerzi Never give up :) Try this one.

Comment: Yay! it's working. Thanks, Ivan, you made my day.